# Starting with WPF Development for Windows Surface Pro 4 tablet

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml

I am new in windows app development. Actually I want to develop an app for Windows surface pro 4 tablet using WPF(XAML). So I have to use Plain WPF application or Surface SDK ? I am not sure that Plain WPF application will support for surface tablet. Am I correct?

Comment: Love thy [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727733.aspx).

Comment: Surface SDK is for the Microsoft PixelSense table computer, formerly known as Microsoft Surface. Besides that, you may want to write a Universal Window Platform (UWP) app, instead of WPF.

Comment: Thanks Clemens. got an idea. I have to use UWP instead of WPF

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation regarding [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: That means my question is not in correct way ?